# Query db to receive array of objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

### Scenario

Lets say i have a model book with fields:

- id
- name
- author
- rating

(Keeping it simple :) )

Now lets say we have multiple rows of books in our db.

---

### Question

How can I query the db to receive a array of Book objects who have the same author for instance?

`array = Book.objects.filter(author='JK Rowling')` --> returns a QuerySet
But i want an array of Book objects.

```
[{id:1, name:'HP 1', author: 'JK Rowling'},{id:2, name:'HP 2', author: 'JK Rowling'},{id:3, name:'HP 3', author: 'JK Rowling'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A queryset *is* an array of Book objects. What you're showing there is a list of dictionaries, which is something else entirely. You can achieve that by using `values()`:

```
Book.objects.filter(author='JK Rowling').values()
```

Note that by doing this you lose all the functionality associated with returning the actual Book objects themselves, such as the ability to call their methods, modify and save them back to the db, etc. Unless you have a really good reason, you should stick to the actual queryset.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a dictionary from an arbitrary object by using the `__dict__` special method.

A comprehension of the queryset will allow you to build a list of these dictionaries.

e.g. 
    `queryset = Book.objects.filter(author='JK Rowling')`
    `array = [book.__dict__ for book in queryset]`

Comment: This is unlikely to be useful. For example, it would include internal attributes like `_state` which OP almost certainly doesn't want in their dict representation.